# ¿Cómo obtener los objetos en radio en una matriz?

Tags: java

Ejemplo: si tengo una zona y quiero mostrar las zonas en radio mediante una duración de viaje/distancia de zona a zona en una matriz

Desde ya, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Kurune, bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] para que mejores la calidad de tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Levi Arista, eso fue de gran ayuda y estaré al pendiente de otras cosas más para mejorar dentro de la comunidad, se aceptan todo tipo de posts para mejorar :)

Comment: Tenes que agregar a tu pregunta el codigo que intentate, y un ejemplo claro de que buscas.

Comment: De nada @Kurune, suerte!.